# Running play 2 app on tomcat with play2war

Tags: tomcat, hosting, playframework-2.0, war, reverse-proxy

I have project that runs great from the play commandline invocation. I want to get this app hosted. I found  out that play2war will create a war file. In order to run it in apache, i have renamed the war to root.war and deployed. when i go to http:localhost:8080 blank page. I tried following the instructions on the play site, it seems i also need play running from the commandline. I am not sure how exactly to have the reverse proxy working, as it does not tell which config file to edit.

with play2war war file, will I still need to do this. Is there a way to get this war be hosted in a regular provider  or run in my install of tomcat. Do I need to provide a web.xml and manifest, are these necessary ?

Can some one provide the list of steps if possible - I am lost - All the excitement I felt with the development process is evaporating with the deployment nightmare.

All options to natively host like Heroku is fairly expensive compared to other hosting.

Comment: Let's say that Apache is not used to run war files. Tomcat is.

Answer (score 0):

You have to deploy you application in some kind of way.There are different ways of doing that.

- the command line. You simply launch it using the stage/package or start command. Checkout [the documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/Production) on that part.
- Packaging your file as a WAR and deploy that war into an application server. Tomcat for instance.

Once you have your application running it should be accessible via it's traditionnal port. (8080 for tomcat, 9000 for the command line)

After that, you can add a reverse proxy. The whole point of a reverse proxy is to listen on a common port, let's say 80 and forward all requests to another port. Let's say 9000.

As a reverse proxy you can use differents servers as well :

- [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) most common server. It has a great ecosystem but is not that performant.
- [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule), lighttpd, etc. are better as reverse proxy. Give those a try.